Does Microsoft Launcher allow setting badge numbers programmatically?
Some default Android home launchers (e.g. Samsung's, Sony's) still allow setting of application icon badge number to desired value programmatically, e.g. by broadcasting a specific intent to them or updating content values on their given URI.
Does Microsoft Launcher provide such functionality too? (Which method? Any details how to achieve it?)
(Please note, I'm not interested in "number of currently pending notifications for given app", which seems to be the "default" badge number meaning nowadays - if even shown at all).
